# How to interpret datetime as User's local timezone in Acumatica

Tags: acumatica

We have a button "Start" that populates the dateStarted field to DateTime.Now..

When retrieving datetime, it always shows the server's date/time instead of user's local timezone version. How do i make it work like lastModifiedDateTime/CreatedDateTime that whenever we view it it's formatted as user's local timezone. I tried UseTimeZone = true/false but nothing is working

Here is my code that is not working

```
#region DateStarted
    public abstract class dateStarted : PX.Data.IBqlField
    {
    }
    protected DateTime? _DateStarted;
    [PXDBDateAndTime(DisplayNameDate = "Date Started", DisplayNameTime = "Time", UseTimeZone = true)]

    public virtual DateTime? DateStarted
    {
        get
        {
            return this._DateStarted;
        }
        set
        {
            this._DateStarted = value;
        }
    }
    #endregion
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like just using `PX.Common.PXTimeZoneInfo.Now` is enough to do the job.

`PX.Common.PXTimeZoneInfo` also has `UtcNow`, `UtcToday`, and `Today` if needed

Answer (score 1):

Look up the code of class `PXDBDateAndTime` in `Source Code` screen SM204570. For debugging purpose you can copy the whole attribute and rename it to something else like `PXDBDateAndTimeDebug`:
[image]

```
[PXDBDateAndTimeDebug(DisplayNameDate = "Date Started", DisplayNameTime = "Time", UseTimeZone = true)]
```

With that approach you can debug `SetUseTimeZone` and `GetTimeZone` methods. The time zone used is coming from `LocaleInfo.GetTimeZone` method and you should debug that too:

```
public static PXTimeZoneInfo GetTimeZone()
{
    if (!PXContext.PXIdentity.IsAnonymous() && PXContext.PXIdentity.TimeZone != null)
    {
        return PXContext.PXIdentity.TimeZone;
    }

    return PXTimeZoneInfo.Invariant;
}
```

The issue here is that from your question we can't tell if there's actually a problem with Acumatica time zone handling or if the user profile time zone is properly configured in your instance or if the result you're expecting is actually a valid ISO conversion as done by the DotNet framework. Debugging step by step should reveal what's going on.

Comment: I have noticed that in some configurations the displayed value is in local time but stored in the DB as UTC time. Also if the user doesn't have a time zone set i think it will use the server time zone. Just some thoughts.

Comment: Also can try to use PX.Common.PXTimeZoneInfo.Now vs DateTime.Now to see if that is in the user timezone. Its possible the set of the field to start is incorrect? I have run into similar issue before - i will have to find the configuration i use but for getting the Now time i always use PX.Common.PXTimeZoneInfo.Now

Comment: I'm also thinking that the user time zone configuration doesn't match the expected locale. Without time zone configuration it should default to PXTimeZoneInfo.Invariant GMT 0000 (according to the source code).

Answer (score 1):

After analyzing how CreatedDateTime and LastModifiedDatetime and other dates behave the same, the problem is in the input. So i created the following code to save the correct datetime with regards to the current user's timezone.

```
 public static class DateTimeHelper
{
    public static DateTime? Now()
    {
        var test = LocaleInfo.GetTimeZone();
        PXTimeZoneInfo timezone = LocaleInfo.GetTimeZone();
        DateTime dt = DateTime.UtcNow;
        dt = PXTimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(dt, timezone);
        return dt;
    }
}
```

and the implementation:

```
  public PXAction<CQLMChecklists> startButton;
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Start", Visible = true)]
    [PXButton()]
    public virtual void StartButton()
    {
        if (Document.Current != null)
        {
            CQLMChecklists doc = Document.Current;

            Actions.PressSave();


            CommenceChecklist(DateTimeHelper.Now(), DateTimeHelper.Now().Value, ref doc);
            Document.Update(doc);
        }
        Actions.PressSave();
    }
```

Comment: Did you try PX.Common.PXTimeZoneInfo.Now which looks like its doing something similar to your Now method?

Comment: Hi Brendan, yes, that's correct. I'll be using that. Thanks.